# OpenDir error /proc file : No such file or directory

Tags: c, file, directory, operating-system, system

I am trying to open the /proc directory (with an intention to read PID and some other details of running processes), using following C code, but it is giving error "No such file or directory", but I can browse the proc directory using unix commands in terminal.

Can someone say what's wrong in my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *procdir;
    if(!(procdir=opendir("/proc"))){
        perror("opendir failed!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unix commands :

```
$ ./a
opendir failed!: No such file or directory

MINGW64 ~/unix
$ /proc
bash: /proc: Is a directory

MINGW64 ~/unix
$ cd /proc

MINGW64 /proc
$ ls
465      cygdrive     loadavg  mounts      registry    self   sys      
version
503      devices      meminfo  net         registry32  stat   sysvipc
cpuinfo  filesystems  misc     partitions  registry64  swaps  uptime
```

Comment: Your program works fine on linux. But, you're using `mingw64` under windows. I'm not familiar with `mingw64`, but more familiar with `cygwin64`. The `/proc` isn't a windows thing but is emulated by the given development package. For example, ordinary/standard windows utilities would _not_ find it. You'd have to be running (e.g.) a cygwin utility from under the cygwin shell

Comment: Was `a` built as a native Windows executable (or as an msys/cygwin executable)?

Comment: Thank you! The problem was with using MINGW. I switched to CYGWIN64, and the code is working fine.

Comment: I am compiling the C code using gcc, to create a.exe file.